# ANOVA with complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, statistics

I want to analyze my data with respect to their within- and between-group variance (an ANOVA analysis).

While I am familiar with the typical approach for real numbers, I have in my case complex numbers at hand (coherence values within a signal processing project).
Can ANOVA be implemented in the canonical manner for complex numbers?

Does the use of the F-statistic requires to transform the terms relevant for an ANOVA to real numbers?

Comment: I think [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/) on stats stackexchange could be of interest to you

Comment: This is better suited on the stats site and I doubt 'complex-analysis' or 'analysis' is the right tag here.